# Get value from jstl text field through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I am working on a project in spring with jstl and jQuery. I have a text field in jsp page as -

```
<form:input path="suv.userName" cssClass="textField" placeholder="Username (Email-Id)"/>
```

Problem is - when i am trying to get the field value through jQuery as - `alert($("#suv.userName").val());`

I am getting the undefined message. But when i am trying with javascript as -

```
alert(document.getElementById("suv.userName").value);
```

I am getting the proper value.
I think there is something problem in **suv.userName** haveing a '.' between. Please help how to get the value in jQuery.

Comment: @Felix kling The question that you have linked looks like a vague one.. :(

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Really? I think it's pretty clear. The other question is about using an ID containing a `.` in a jQuery selector. What's vague about that?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I agree with it now. I just had a closer look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.` is a [meta-character](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you have to escape it with `\\` in order to make that selector valid.

Try,

```
alert($("#suv\\.userName").val());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nMaw9/)